# Accessing the requested url with the query helper

Tags: c#, query-string, querystringparameter, query-help

what I need;

api/GetCharacteristicsBulk?versionCode=RTUK8L1&language=2
go to this address.

```
 var urlCode = selectedVersionCode + "&" + "language=" + language;
 string url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString($"{_urls.BaseUrl}{_urls.SapCharacteristicService.GetCharacteristicsBulk}", "versionCode", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlCode));
```

when i run this;
api/GetCharacteristicsBulk?RTUK8L1%262=RTUK8L1%25262.
I get a result as above.

api/GetCharacteristicsBulk?versionCode=RTUK8L1&language=2 What should I do to get the output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses a string [AddQueryString(String, IDictionary<String,String>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.addquerystring?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-webutilities-queryhelpers-addquerystring(system-string-system-collections-generic-idictionary((system-string-system-string)))) overload will give you the correct result.

```
Dictionary<string, string> queryArguments = new()
{
    { "versionCode", "RTUK8L1" },
    { "language", "2" }
};

var results = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(
    "api/GetCharacteristicsBulk", 
    queryArguments);
```

Result `api/GetCharacteristicsBulk?versionCode=RTUK8L1&language=2`